# Select specific cell after Inputting values In previous cells

Tags: vba, excel, cell, selection

so I have an input sheet and want to move the activated cell to another cell after data has been typed in/chosen.
So far I've got this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If Range("F11").Value <> "" Then
Range("F13").Select

End If
End Sub
```

But the problem is this does not seem to work with more cells and ranges for some reason. So for example if then F13 is selected I want to move to F16. If F16 is selected I want to move to F17. So no rule here like always 2 rows down. How can I solve this?

Best

Comment: If there are no rules to follow then solve it by writing out each possible event and corresponding outcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simply type of a boilerplate, which can be increased further, following a specific business logic.

If you want to Add `Range("D5")` with 3 rows, then add it to the Union in this line: `If Intersect(Target, Union(Range("F16"), Range("F13")))` and then make a `Case Range("D5")`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Row > Rows.Count - 2 Then Exit Sub
    If Target = vbNullString Then Exit Sub        
    If Intersect(Target, Union(Range("F16"), Range("F13"))) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Select Case Target
        Case Range("F16")
            Target.Offset(1).Select
        Case Range("F13")
            Target.Offset(2).Select
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Question: Since `Target` is a range object, shouldn't we check for Nothing e.g. `If Not Target Is Nothing Then ` ?

Comment: @KostasK. Target will never be nothing but it could be empty or more than a single cell.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: Thanks! But the thing is I do not have a general rule such as always 2 rows down, but the next cell always depends on the previous one selected.

Comment: @Alex - without a rule it is tough to build it. I have edited to make it look a bit like a boilerplate.